# Get the id field of an array

Tags: php, kohana

I have a request with Kohana which returns an array, just like this :

```
$query = DB::select()
    ->from('environnement')
    ->where('utilisateur_id','=', 'd83fa9a71cc1c414011cc1dbeb270026') 
    ->where('region_id','=', $region_selectionnee);

$id_env = $query->execute();

return $id_env->as_array();
```

I call the request in my controller and `var_dump` the result. I get :

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> array(4) { 
        ["id"]=> string(32) "d83fa9a71cc1c414011cc1de74270027" 
        ["courant"]=> string(1) "0" 
        ["region_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
        ["utilisateur_id"]=> string(32) "d83fa9a71cc1c414011cc1dbeb270026" 
    } 
}
```

Now, I want to get the `id` field of this array, but I don't know how to do. I tried with `$id_environnement->id` but it says

> Trying to get property of non-object

I also tried with `$id_environnement["id"]`, but it says :

> Undefined index: id

Can somebody help me to get this id please ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see, the result is an *array*, in which is the object you want. So you have to use `$id_environment[0]["id"]` to get it.

Comment: It says "Trying to get property of non-object" again :/

Comment: Yeah, that's it ! Thanks !! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Arr::path($id_environment, '0.id')
```

This method don't raise exception if array key not exists

Comment: Great ! I will probably use it !! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
$id = DB::select('id')
  ->from('environnement')
  ->where('utilisateur_id','=', 'd83fa9a71cc1c414011cc1dbeb270026') 
  ->where('region_id','=', $region_selectionnee)
  ->limit(1)
  ->execute()
  ->get('id', false);
```

Where the second argument in `get()` is what you want returned if `'id'` is not found (if you don't include a second argument, it will return `null` if `'id'` is not found).

*edit*

You don't have to specify `'id'` within `select()`, but if you *do* specify a field (or fields), `get()` can only retrieve from the specified field(s).